# unable to successfully install yugabytedb on Macos 12.0.1

Tags: yugabytedb, macos-monterey

following Yugabyte standard install for MacOS, it fails to run on 12.0.1, it does run on MacOS 11

marcsair-m:logs Marc$ cat yugabyted.log

[yugabyted start] 2021-11-03 23:07:27,388 INFO:  | 0.0s | cmd = start using config file: /Users/Marc/var/conf/yugabyted.conf (args.config=None)
[yugabyted start] 2021-11-03 23:07:27,389 INFO:  | 0.0s | Found directory /Users/Marc/yugabyte-2.9.1.0/yugabyte-2.9.1.0/bin for file yb-admin
[yugabyted start] 2021-11-03 23:07:27,389 INFO:  | 0.0s | Starting yugabyted...
[yugabyted start] 2021-11-03 23:07:27,391 INFO:  | 0.0s | Daemon grandchild process begins execution.
[yugabyted start] 2021-11-03 23:07:27,392 INFO:  | 0.0s | yugabyted started running with PID 21931.
[yugabyted start] 2021-11-03 23:07:27,392 INFO:  | 0.0s | Changed RLIMIT_NOFILE from 2560 to 64000
[yugabyted start] 2021-11-03 23:07:27,393 INFO:  | 0.0s | Found directory /Users/Marc/yugabyte-2.9.1.0/yugabyte-2.9.1.0/bin for file yb-master
[yugabyted start] 2021-11-03 23:07:27,393 INFO:  | 0.0s | Found directory /Users/Marc/yugabyte-2.9.1.0/yugabyte-2.9.1.0/bin for file yb-tserver
[yugabyted start] 2021-11-03 23:07:27,394 INFO:  | 0.0s | About to start master with cmd /Users/Marc/yugabyte-2.9.1.0/yugabyte-2.9.1.0/bin/yb-master --stop_on_parent_termination --undefok=stop_on_parent_termination --fs_data_dirs=/Users/Marc/var/data --webserver_interface=0.0.0.0 --metrics_snapshotter_tserver_metrics_whitelist=handler_latency_yb_tserver_TabletServerService_Read_count,handler_latency_yb_tserver_TabletServerService_Write_count,handler_latency_yb_tserver_TabletServerService_Read_sum,handler_latency_yb_tserver_TabletServerService_Write_sum,disk_usage,cpu_usage,node_up --yb_num_shards_per_tserver=1 --ysql_num_shards_per_tserver=1 --cluster_uuid=98ea4dc5-9cd3-4372-8229-3eacd9f44475 --rpc_bind_addresses=127.0.0.1:7100 --server_broadcast_addresses=127.0.0.1:7100 --replication_factor=1 --use_initial_sys_catalog_snapshot --server_dump_info_path=/Users/Marc/var/data/master-info --master_enable_metrics_snapshotter=true --webserver_port=7000 --default_memory_limit_to_ram_ratio=0.35 --instance_uuid_override=00150954eb114f8a82269730e122f288 --master_addresses=127.0.0.1:7100
[yugabyted start] 2021-11-03 23:07:27,396 INFO:  | 0.0s | master started running with PID 21932.
[yugabyted start] 2021-11-03 23:07:27,397 ERROR:  | 0.0s | Failed to create symlink from /Users/Marc/var/data/yb-data/master/logs to /Users/Marc/var/logs/master
[yugabyted start] 2021-11-03 23:07:27,398 INFO:  | 0.0s | Waiting for master
[yugabyted start] 2021-11-03 23:07:27,398 INFO:  | 0.0s | run_process: cmd: [u'/Users/Marc/yugabyte-2.9.1.0/yugabyte-2.9.1.0/bin/yb-admin', u'--init_master_addrs', u'127.0.0.1:7100', u'list_all_masters']
[yugabyted start] 2021-11-03 23:07:27,899 INFO:  | 0.5s | run_process returned -11:
OUT >>

<< ERR >>
<<
[yugabyted start] 2021-11-03 23:07:28,400 ERROR:  | 1.0s | Failed waiting for yb-master... process died.
[yugabyted start] 2021-11-03 23:07:28,402 ERROR:  | 1.0s | Failed to setup master. Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./bin/yugabyted", line 972, in setup_master
if retry_op(self.wait_master, timeout):
File "./bin/yugabyted", line 2654, in retry_op
return func()
File "./bin/yugabyted", line 929, in wait_master
raise RuntimeError("process died unexpectedly.")
RuntimeError: process died unexpectedly.

For more information, check the logs in /Users/Marc/var/logs
[yugabyted start] 2021-11-03 23:07:28,403 INFO:  | 1.0s | Shutting down...

Comment: Can you run `./bin/yugabyted collect_logs` and upload the zip package?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: no - SO wont let me upload any files.